# Allow security group to rdp to certain computer OU only

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, active-directory, group-policy, windows-server

Basically I am trying to replicate my work Active Directory at home for educational purposes.

At work we have computers and laptops from different sites grouped into different OU e.g Laptop1 and Computer1 would be in BRISTOL OU, and Laptop2 and Computer2 would be in BIRMINGHAM OU,

My manager can RDP to any site because of his permissions (which I totally agree with) and I can only RDP to the computers of site BRISTOL, now I know that it will be to do with a security group and group policies.

I just want to know what group policy settings will allow you assign Remote Access to different OU in group policy.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the necessary permissions on the domain to even make these changes?

Comment: It's on a home lab that I've setup just to replicate my work organisation.

Comment: I assume your trying to determine what changes must be done to modify the work organization by having the home lab or are you trying to simply configure the home lab similar to the work organization?

Comment: Just trying to make the home lab similar to the work environment, to get a better understanding without messing up anything in the work environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RDP control to a given computer is based on the user account attempting the RDC being in, or in a group within the local computer's Remote Desktop User's group.

The normal way to place AD user objects or security groups within that local group is using a Group Policy.

Group Policies can be applied to specific objects or groups of objects based on a very wide array of criteria, ranging from the Organization Unit (OU) they exist within to really any criteria that can be queried by Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI).

The easiest way to assign individual security groups to the Remote Desktop User local group of the computers within a specific OU is to Link and Activate a group policy on that specific OU that assigns the AD users/groups to the local group. You'll find this policy under `Computer Configuration \ Preferences \ Control Panel Settings \ Local Users and Groups.`

Comment: That's perfect, exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.